# Json in Android : Unexpected character (<) at position 0

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to use Json for an android online db connection. Problem is no matter what i try i get the ever so popular Unexpected character (<) at position 0 error.

here is my method:

```
 public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:link to my file.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        resulString="Couldn't connect to database";
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        String s = "";
        JSONParser parser_obj = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) parser_obj.parse(result.toString());

        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s +
                    "Id : "+json.getInt("Id")+" Name: "+json.getString("ShopName")+"\n"+
                    "Icon : "+json.getInt("ShopIcon")+"Description:"+json.getString("ShopDesc")+"\n\n";
        }

        resulString=s;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

tried both get and post methods
heres my php file:

!php[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA0bu.png)

the connection is established but theres no result and loggcat displays that error.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I finally found the solution:
simply added these 2 headers:

```
 request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); // or application/jsonrequest
 request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

also make sure that the url in your HTTP is perfect.

And this was of awesome help for testing the connection:
http://www.requestmaker.com